# what functionality 'FileIOXml.<>c.<>9.a' implements

Tags: c#

I read a code to realize queue type conversion, and the character < >, I don't quite understand what function this character realizes here。
Here **FileIOXml.<>c.<>9**.a Unable to understand what functionality 'FileIOXml.<>c.<>9.a' implements。Syntax error during copying and recompiling
Class "FileIOXml" have method name "c" and "a", Method "a" has multiple overloads.

```
string innerText9 = string.Join(",", Array.ConvertAll<Color, string>((Color[])a_.Value, new Converter<Color, string>(FileIOXml.<>c.<>9.a)));
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics

Comment: Don't post code snippets as images.

Comment: we used for <generic types>.  T means generic. for more info.  
Array.ConvertAll<TInput,TOutput>(TInput[], Converter<TInput,TOutput>) Method

Answer (score 1):

< T > used for Generic purposes and
we can pass any type to it. visit below link. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics

```
Array.ConvertAll<TInput,TOutput>(TInput[], Converter<TInput,TOutput>)
```

here we can pass any type as <TInput,TOutput>
Fore example.

```
int[] intArray = Array.ConvertAll<string,int>(strArray, int.Parse);
```